# C array assign & access

Tags: c, arrays, pic, uart

I'm writing C code in a PIC16F1824, and are using UART.
I had this for receiving:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
   while(!PIR1bits.RCIF);
   RX_arr[i] = RCREG;
   while(PIR1bits.RCIF);
}
```

`RX_arr` is an array declared as `int RX_arr[9];`

`RCREG` is the UART receving register and is supposed to have

```
0xFF 86 00 00 00 00 00 00 47;
```

**Question1:**

When i = 1, `RX_arr[0]`'s value(`0xFF` in this case) also changes when `RX_arr[1] = RCREG` is executed(Both postion 0 and 1 have 0x86). 
Later I found using this segment of code instead of the for loop above will successfully assign one byte into each position:

```
if(!RCSTAbits.FERR && !RCSTAbits.OERR){
        RX_arr[0] = RCREG;
}
```

However, the byte saved is wrong, only the 0xFF is always correct, other bytes are some other values. I found the OERR bit is set, which indicates an overrun error(2 byte FIFO buffer is full before accessed). How can I receive all the bytes in `RCREG`?

**Question2:**

After I get the response in question1, I read the useful information in it, which is in byte 2 and 3, and I made a variable called `data`. In my case the data is a sampled temperature, and I want to collect 20 samples,and save them in an array called `ppm_array`. `sum_ppm` is supposed to be the sum of all 20 samples, and will add the new sampled temperature to it every time a new sample is collected. When I run `sum_ppm += ppm_array[i]`(sum_ppm = 0, ppm_array[0] = 1616, and the rest of the positions are 0),I got sum_ppm = 4508160. Why isn't it 1616??? Am I adding the address of them?

```
data = RX_arr[2] * 256 + RX_arr[3];
ppm_array[i] = data;
sum_ppm += ppm_array[i]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: why don't you use an interrupt for sending/receiving UART? That will be more efficient that wasting CPU time polling for data

Comment: PIC is slow. Be sure you're fully inited before any data is sent to it and you enter the read loop ASAP. You may have to clear OERR and wait for the _next_ "start" byte (e.g. the 0xFF). Is your baud rate and clock multiplier set correctly [are you _sure_ :-)]? In your 1st code block, the 2nd `while` isn't needed [AFAICT].

Comment: How is Rx_arr declared?

Comment: "RX_arr is an array declared as int RX_arr[9];"